# Getting img element from html string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-parsing

I have the following html string:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <th>
              <tr>
                <img src=""/>
              </tr>
            </th>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to get only the `img` element?

So in this case I want a string like this `<img src=""/>`.

More specific example:

```
$wikiDOM = $("<document>"+ wikiHTML+ "</document>");
var infobox = $wikiDOM.find('.infobox').html();
if(infobox != 'undefined' && infobox !== ""){
    var img = infobox.filter( 'img' );
    console.log( img[0].outerHTML );
}
```

where wikiHTML is the request i make to wikipedia api in json format for several searchterms.

Edit:

return from img and infobox:

```
image:[object Object] 
infobox[object Object] 
image:[object Object] 
infobox[object Object]
image:[object Object] 
infobox[object Object]
image:[object Object] 
infobox[object Object] 
image:[object Object] 
infobox[object Object]
image:[object Object] 
infobox[object Object]
image:[object Object] 
infobox[object Object] 
image:[object Object] 
infobox[object Object]
```

Comment: Do you actually have a string? or it that the source code?

Comment: I actually have a string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, for example in jQuery you will need to pass your string to `$` function and then get `<img>` by `img` selector:

```
var html = $( '<html><head></head><body><table><tbody><th><tr><img src=""/></tr></th></tbody></table></body></html>' )
var img = html.filter( 'img' );
console.log( img );
```

To get `img` html code you will need:

```
console.log( img[0].outerHTML )
```

**EDIT**
So according to your edit your code should be:

```
$wikiDOM = $("<document>"+ wikiHTML+ "</document>");
var infobox = $( $wikiDOM.find('.infobox').html() );
if(infobox != 'undefined' && infobox !== ""){
    var img = infobox.filter( 'img' );
    console.log( img[0].outerHTML );
}
```

As you can see I have added `$()` around `$wikiDOM.find('.infobox').html()`. You were getting `undefined` because `innerHTML` DOM property doesn't have `filter` method. Only jQuery do.

Comment: i am getting undefined in html.find('img');

Comment: @João ok, use `filter` instead of `find` method. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/ex8Hk/

Comment: In my case i have a var like this. var infobox = $wikiDOM.find('.infobox').html(); to get html of infobox from wikipedia. with filter i still get undefined.

Comment: This is off-topic. But if you want to parse wikipedia, you might consider using their JSON API http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Data_formats

Comment: i am getting json wikipedia infobox for several searchterms but it is not relevant. because i than have the html inside the infobox. i added code to question.

Comment: now its the same problem but in outerHTML of img[0].

Comment: What `console.log( img )` and `console.log( infobox )` returns?

Comment: and what `console.log( $wikiDOM.find('.infobox').html() )` returns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58266/discussion-between-joao-and-antyrat).

Answer (score 0):

This would do:

```
var image = $("img").html();
```

Comment: This will return nothing as `html()` method return's child nodes of current selector and works like `innerHTML`, you need `outerHTML` here